# Azure Active Directory Authentication 401, Bearer Token The signature is invalid

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-5.0

I have Web API application in .NET CORE 5 and client app in Angular 10. I have registered both application in Azure Active Directory for `Authentication` purpose. I have successfully generate token in Angular app by providing the user credential but get 401 error when I make the API call. The http response confirms the The signature is invalid. I have tried various things but no luck. I am using library @azure/msal-angular' on angular side

`error`
[image]

```
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

### Web API

`appsettings.json`

```
AzureAd": {
"Domain": "MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com",
"Tenant": "MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com",
"TanantId": "3xxxxxxx-zzzz-yyyy-bwww-00000000000",
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"ClientId": "8f9c5e55-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Audience": "8f9c5e55-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/3xxxxxxx-zzzz-yyyy-bwww-00000000000/v2.0",
"ResourceId": "https://MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com/8f9c5e55-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
```

`Starup.cs`

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(jwtConfig =>
            {
                jwtConfig.Audience = configuration["AzureAdB2C:ResourceId"];
                jwtConfig.Authority = $"{configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}{configuration["AzureAdB2C:TanantId"]}";
                jwtConfig.SaveToken = true;
                jwtConfig.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidAudience = jwtConfig.Audience
                };
                jwtConfig.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
                    OnMessageReceived = OnMessageReceived,
                    OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated
                };
            });


   services.AddCors(options =>
          options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
          {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
            })); 

   private static Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
   {

   }

   private static Task OnMessageReceived(MessageReceivedContext context)
   {
   }

   private static Task OnTokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext arg)
   {
   }
```

### Angular

following code call the API along with token in header

```
const myheaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`,
});

this.http.get('https://localhost:44362/v2/Site/GetSecureMessage', {headers: myheaders})
    .subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    })
```

}

### Current Scope on Web API Application

[image]

Comment: Can you inspect the token at e.g. https://jwt.ms and check if the audience, issuer etc. match?

Comment: I check audience which is aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", and is very different to application in Azure TenantId or ClientId

Comment: not really sure what I am missing or how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that when you are acquiring the token, you use a scope defined for your API and not e.g. "User.Read".
You seem to have received an access token for Microsoft Graph API, which won't work with your API.

Comment: So If I understanding correctly, I go to 1- Azure Portal, 2- Go to Application Registered for Client 3- Go to API Permissions 4- Click on 'Add a Permission' 5 Choose Web API Application???

Comment: No, you need to define a scope under Expose an API. Then when requesting an access token, use that scope's full id for the scope value.

Comment: This is Web API Application registration in Azure ?

Comment: I have already define scope, I put screen shot in the end of question how I know it is User.Read? and change to different one?

Comment: Is that scope is correct ?

Comment: In API Permission, please can you add that scope? I have the same issue but resolved by adding it to API Permission